# How to remove the parent numeric keys of php array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I've an array in php something like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40173
            [1] => 514081
            [2] => 363885
            [3] => 891382
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40173
            [1] => 5181
            [2] => 385
            [3] => 891382
        )

)
```

Now I want to remove the parents indexes 0,1... and finally want to get all the values (only unique values).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible approach is using [**call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr)**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) idiom to flatten an array, then extracting unique values with [**array_unique()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$new_arr = array_unique(
  call_user_func_array('array_merge', $old_arr));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/124251). Obviously, it'll work with array of any length.

Answer (score 3):

```
$startArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40173
        [1] => 514081
        [2] => 363885
        [3] => 891382
    ),
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 40173
        [1] => 5181
        [2] => 385
        [3] => 891382
    )

);
//Edited to handle more the 2 subarrays
$finalArray = array();

foreach($startArray as $tmpArray){
    $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, $tmpArray);
}

$finalArray = array_unique($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [Using RecursiveArrayIterator Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

```
$objarr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($yourarray));
foreach($objarr as $v) {
    $new_arr[]=$v;
}
print_r(array_unique($new_arr));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124330)

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40173
    [1] => 514081
    [2] => 363885
    [3] => 891382
    [5] => 5181
    [6] => 385
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$show_unique = array_unique($new_array);
print_r($show_unique);
```

`array_merge` is merging the array's, `array_unique` is removinge any duplicate values.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($big_array as $sub_array) {
    array_merge($new_array, $sub_array);
}

$new_array = array_unique($new_array);
```

(code not tested, this just a concept)

Comment: Indeed, but the rest of the answer is, so what's the problem?

Comment: Good SO answer explains what is the problem and solution + shows code. Your one looks more like comment and there is no reason for person reading the "answer" to believe it will solve the problem. If you don't feel typing one sentence explaining your approach - just add your suggestion as comment.

Comment: You can't add readable code to  a comment. But of cource you're always welcome to edit and improve the answer, go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$Arr = array(array(40173, 514081, 363885, 891382),
             array(40173,5181, 385,891382));

$newArr = array();

foreach($Arr as $val1)
{

foreach($val1 as $val2)
{  
     array_push($newArr, $val2);
}
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_unique($newArr));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40173
    [1] => 514081
    [2] => 363885
    [3] => 891382
    [5] => 5181
    [6] => 385
)
```

Refer: https://eval.in/124240

-- 
Thanks